# Optimizing rendering through packing vertex buffers

Tags: opengl, vulkan

John Carmack recently tweeted:

> "Another outdated habit is making separate buffer objects for vertexes
>   and indexes."

I am afraid I don't fully understand what he means. Is he implying that packing all 3D data including vertex, index, and joint data into a single vertex buffer is optimal compared to separate buffers for each? And, if so, would such a technique apply only to OpenGL or could a Vulkan renderer benefit as well?

Comment: It should also be noted that this "outdated habit" is actively being encouraged by WebGL, thanks to implementations frequently being implemented atop pre-12 Direct3D versions. And D3D actively *requires* you to make them separate buffers.

Comment: Interesting point, although I am personally not interested in web programming or compatibility with pre-2016 tech. Vulkan-next, on the other hand, could impose such limitations in its quest for compatibility with Apple and the like...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think he means there's no particular need to put them in different buffer objects. You probably don't want to interleave them at fine-granularity, but putting e.g. all the indices for a mesh at the beginning of a buffer and then all the vertex data for the mesh following it is not going to be any worse than using separate buffer objects. Use offsets to point the binding points at the correct location in the buffer.

Whether it's *better* to put them in one buffer I don't know: if it is, I think it's probably ancillary things like having fewer larger memory allocations tends to be a little more efficient, you (or the driver) can do one large copy instead of two smaller ones when copies are necessary, etc.

Edit: I'd expect this all to apply to both GL and Vulkan.

Comment: I was hoping to get performance details or some resources on the subject where I could dig a bit deeper. In my Vulkan rendering code I actually make use of a custom memory allocator that loads models into GPU and then binds them to the vertex/index buffer when an draw command on such a model is finally performed

Comment: @RWilco8 I believe [Vulkan Memory Management](https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-memory-management) article mentions this technique. We have bit of a follow-up discussion in https://forums.khronos.org/showthread.php/13237-Memory-Management-One-buffer

Answer (score 0):

John Carmack has replied with an answer regarding his original tweet:

> "The performance should be the same, just less management.  I wouldn't bother changing old code."
>              ...
>   "It isn't a problem, it just isn't necessary on modern hardware.  No big efficiency to packing them, just a modest management overhead."

So perhaps it isn't an outdated habit at all especially since it goes against the intended use-case for most APIs and in some cases can break compatibility -
 as noted by Nico.